# How to convert an event to an IObservable when it doesn't conform to the standard .NET event pattern

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an delegate that looks like this:

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(int arg1, int arg2);
```

And an event that looks like this:

```
public event MyDelegate SomethingHappened;
```

Is there some easy way to create an IObservable sequence for this event? I'd like to do something like this (but it doesn't compile):

```
var obs = Observable.FromEventPattern<int, int>(this, "SomethingHappened");
var subscription = obs.Subscribe(x,y => DoSomething(x, y));
```

....

```
private void DoSomething(int value1, int value2)
{
...
}
```

Comment: I am wondering if this Article would benefit you in your current situation http://www.dofactory.com/net/observer-design-pattern also `Jon Skeet` has an SO posting on what looks to be similar as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274815/how-to-use-observable-fromevent-with-static-events

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a way to do this using `Observable.FromEvent` as follows.

Lets create a class `Test` to encapsulate the delegate and event definition:

```
public class Test
{   
    public delegate void MyDelegate(int arg1, int arg2);

    public event MyDelegate SomethingHappened;

    public void RaiseEvent(int a, int b)
    {
        var temp = SomethingHappened;
        if(temp != null)
        {
            temp(a, b);
        }
    }    
}
```

Now, because the delegate has two arguments which are not neatly packaged into a subclass of `EventArgs`, we must use a conversion function to package them into a suitable containing type. If you recall the signature of the `OnNext` method of `IObservable` it should be clear why we have to do this - we can only supply a single argument here.

You can create your own type for this, but I will be lazy and use a `Tuple<int,int>`. We can then use the overload of `Observable.FromEvent` with the conversion function as follows:

```
var test = new Test();

var obs = Observable.FromEvent<Test.MyDelegate, Tuple<int,int>>(
    handler => (a, b) => handler(Tuple.Create(a,b)),
    h => test.SomethingHappened += h,
    h => test.SomethingHappened -= h
);
```

To be clear, what we are supplying in that first parameter is a function that accepts an OnNext handler (in this case of type `Action<Tuple<int,int>>`) and returns a delegate that can be subscribed to the event (of type `MyDelegate`). This delegate will be invoked for each event and will in turn invoke the OnNext handler passed in from the `Subscribe` call. Thus we will end up with a stream of type `IObservable<Tuple<int,int>>`.

With obs in place, we can subscribe like so:

```
var subscription = obs.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Item1 + " " + x.Item2));
```

And test with this:

```
test.RaiseEvent(1, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions, especially James! It does exactly what I need.

Comment: The first parameter to `FromEvent` can be simplified to just `handler => (a, b) => handler(Tuple.Create(a, b))`.  There's no need for the statement expression, assigning the delegate to a variable, explicitly stating the delegate, or any of that.  It'll be inferred by the lambda.

Comment: @Servy Yes, quite right - just a result of how I hashed out the answer. I've put that in.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Observable before, but it looks like the `Observable.FromEvent` method does what you want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229271(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: This will not work. `FromEventPattern` and `FromEvent` both assume the `void (object, TEventArgs)` signature. OP has a `void (int, int)` signature.

Comment: Ah, I see that now. I'll leave this up for a while, since your comment clarifies the difficulty.

Comment: @TimothyShields - not quite true - the overload with a conversion function will see you through, as per my answer.

Comment: @JamesWorld Nice, I didn't know that overload existed.